# Face Detection on iPhone using OpenCV and LBP

Tags: iphone, xcode, optimization, opencv, face-detection

I have been successfully working with the Haar algorithm in OpenCV-2.1.0 (cvHaarDetectObjects) to detect faces in pictures and video frames from within an Objective-C project for iOS 4.2. However, the processing time for the video frames still takes about 1-2 seconds on the iPhone 4 under most conditions. An example of the code I am using is given below:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"haarcascade_frontalface_alt" ofType:@"xml"];

    CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = 
            (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], 
                                             NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    CvSeq* faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(small_image, cascade, storage, 1.2, 0, 
                                       0 |CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH |CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT, cvSize(30, 30));
```

I have tried multiple optimization techniques, including smart application of ROI, and the use of integers rather than floats. Yet these changes have taken vast amounts of time and had only a minor benefit.

It has been suggested to me that utilisation of LBP could significantly reduce the face detection time. I have been experimenting with and searching for ways to implement LBP, but to no avail. In opencv, there is a cascade file (lbpcascade_frontalface.xml), yet I cannot find any suggestions for how to use it.

Any help would be appreciated, including other optimization techniques and Google links that I may have missed in my searching. Accuracy of detection is not critical so long as it is reasonably effective.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to determine where the performance bottlenecks are in your application. Chances are they are different from what you think they might be.

Also, check out [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) performance guide.