# object detection when we open iphone camera

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Face Detection on iPhone using OpenCV and LBP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921260/face-detection-on-iphone-using-opencv-and-lbp)
>   [OpenCV IOS real-time template matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583062/opencv-ios-real-time-template-matching)

In my app am using **opencv** in that am performing **canny edge detection** but I want to recognize **object only** like face detection.

How can we do this by using opencv.

Any one can suggest or help me.

Thank in advance.